# How to pass data from a draggable item to a connected sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Please take a look at [this jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/arasbm/ghMaP/3/)

What I am trying to achieve is to allow user to drag one of the three items on top and drop them into the sorted list. I have added a custom helper which is a placeholder right now and will be used for showing a preview of what that item will look like.

For the sake of discussion lets say the three draggable elements are *source items*, and what ends up in the sortable list is *target items*. What I am having difficulty is passing the right content to the `stop` function in the sortable list and inserting that content into the list instead of default clone of the source item. I also want to pass along some additional information with the source item. For example I want to know in the stop function if the element came from one of draggable source items or it is just one of the target items that is being reordered.

If you check the console you can see some of the unsuccessful attempts that I have made. I tried setting values in `event.data` but I get `TypeError: event.data is null` in the start and stop functions of the sortable list. So I think I am missing something here.

To reiterate my question, there are two related issues I am facing:

1. How do I pass some data from when source item is being dragged to when it is dropped inside the sortable list which seems to trigger `start` and `stop` function of the sortable list?
2. How do I insert a custom div inside the list instead of the default clone of the source item?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a tricky question.

The main problem is that the `sortable` and `draggable` widgets working together use clones of elements and not the elements themselves.

As the [JQuery `data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method store data for an element, it is not easy to bring the information because of the clone creation behavior described above.

A workaround could be to use a simple `div` to store and retrieve the data in the events callback. It is working because there is always only one element dragged.

Here is the code and the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ghMaP/4/

```
<ul id="draggable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Button</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Text Field</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Image</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable" class="ui-state-highlight">
</ul>

<!-- New div used to store and retrieve data of dragged element -->
<div id="tmp"></div>
```

​

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Shortcut on the temp div
    $tmp = $("#tmp").get(0);

    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) { 
            //Here, we retrieve data from the temp div
            console.log("isNew : ", jQuery.data($tmp, "isNew"));
            console.log("resultHTML : ", jQuery.data($tmp, "resultHTML"));
        }
    });

    $("#draggable li").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        start: function(event, ui) {    

            //Store info in a tmp div         
            jQuery.data($tmp, "isNew", true);
            jQuery.data($tmp, "resultHTML", "<b>Here I will add some custom html to EVENT data</b>");

        },
        helper: function(event) {
            return "<div class='custom-helper'>Custom helper for " + $(this).context.innerHTML + "</div>";   
        },
        revert: "invalid"
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the problem and for your solution. I have to admit I was hoping a simpler way to do this would exist in jquery or jquery-ui. I am not sure if it is a great practice to manipulate dom just to pass data around. However, in this case that is the most elegant workaround I have seen. Thank you again!